# Structure of a rails app that uses third party API's

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new RoR and I can't seem to grasp how to structure my app.

I have an app that pulls data from Google Analytics using [garb](https://github.com/Sija/garb). After doing some number crunching with the data, the app will populate a `Report` model and display the report to the user.

Right now, I'm separating the Google Analytics logic using concerns. In my concerns folder, I have a `GoogleAnalytics` module that is responsible for pulling the data. The `Report` model includes the `GoogleAnalytics` module. Before the number crunching in the `Report` model takes place, I need to clean up and reformat the data. Should this be a responsibility of the `GoogleAnalytics` module or maybe a helper?

Is there a better practice for including third party services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reformatting should go on whatever is responsible for pulling the data from Google Analytics. None of the rest of your app should have to know the format of how Google Analytics returns it's data - the module should convert it into a sensible, standard interface and hide all of that from everyone else.

I would also strongly consider putting this stuff into a service object rather than a module. Including modules gets messy because you when you call a method on an object you don't know where that method is defined. I would only use this pattern if you were including the same module in lots of other models and it was a true DRY play.

A service object would look something like (depending on what params you need to use to pull the data):

```
class GoogleAnalyticsDataFetcher

  attr_accessor :data

  def new ga_id
    @ga_id = ga_id
  end

  def fetch
    @data = do_some_stuff
  end

end
```

and then you could call it either from your controller or wrap it up inside the `Report` model somewhere. Then when you go `GoogleAnalyticsDataFetcher.new(id).fetch` it's incredibly obvious what is going on and where it is defined.